# Let an application use a certain interface

Tags: linux, interface

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

I'm using 2 Interfaces, but I need to let application use the second interface (in my case, eth0:0, the first one is named eth0).

Is it possible? Or, if not, is it possible to connect to an IP with a certain interface?

It's a VPServer, I bought an additional IP, I want to "show" this ip for a certain application or IP-Adress.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depends upon the application but most allow you to bind to a particular interface / address. For example, Apache has the Listen directive and MySQL has bind_address. Can you be more specific?

Comment: It's a TeamSpeak Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about TeamSpeak but it looks like you want to specify the IP address as a value to the `voice_ip` parameter.

See [here](http://media.teamspeak.com/ts3_literature/TeamSpeak%203%20Server%20Quick%20Start.txt).

> - voice_ip (0.0.0.0)
>     IP on which the server instance will listen for incoming voice connections.
>     Default: The server is bound on any IP address.

Perhaps you also need to specify `filetransfer_ip` and `query_ip`.